# The latest object does not compute the latest object added

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a simple add-to-cart function using React.js, The pushing of the product object works, but the computation of `total` seems incorrect. The main problem is it does not compute the latest object added.

```
addProduct = () =>{
    const totalPrice = this.state.shoppingCart.reduce((acc, product) => acc + product.price, 0);
    this.setState({
      shoppingCart: this.state.shoppingCart.concat({ name: 'Milk', price: 100 }),
      total: totalPrice,
    }); 

  };
```

Comment: If the state already has a `total` prop, then why not just add the `price` to the total in one simple `setState` like this: `this.setState(prev => ({ ...prev, shoppingCart: prev.shoppingCart.concat({ name: 'Milk', price: 100}), total: prev.total + 100}));`. And, the initial state could be set like this: `shoppingCard: [], total: 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you adding the latest added product's price to the totalPrice.

I think this function looks better:

```
    addProduct = (product) =>{
    const newCart = [...this.state.shoppingCart,product]
    const totalPrice = newCart.reduce((acc, product) => acc + product.price, 0);
    this.setState({
      shoppingCart: newCart,
    }); 
    this.setState({total : totalPrice});
  };
```

Comment: If `total` is always the sum of all prices of objects in shoppingCart, then storing it on state is the derived state antipattern. It's a antipattern because it leads to bugs; why try to synchronous data when the total is deterministic? Simply call your `reduce` function where you want to display the total and remove it from state.